# How to set up dual monitor 3840 x 1080, single background image

Tags: dual-boot, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have just installed Ubuntu 23.10, "mantic" on my Beelink Mini-S computer.  I have two HDMI monitors, and they are configured for 3840x1080, and I have full access to the dual desktop, I can drag apps across the screens, no problem.

I wish to use a 3840x1080 background image, but I cannot seem to find the settings to get that to display properly in 'panorama' mode.

Please advise.